# Using Openlayers as an event dispatcher

Tags: openlayers

We are currently testing OpenLayers on tops a proprietary image rendering library (which cannot be replaced). We need to figure out a way where the OL events are in sync with the image rendering library.

Currently we tried out panning and zooming:

For panning we used "change:center" event which is also fired when zooming. Is there a possibility where we can use the zooming event without firing "change:center"? If so how can we do it?

Also where can we find the actual DOM events of OL events to access properties?

Comment: You can use `propertychange` and check its zoom in a callback

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the postcompose event that is triggered after a map frame is rendered. This can be used to handle animatyion on a map (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html).